# Remove base folder from url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I'm trying to rewrite

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/folder/page/display-6.html
```

to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/page/display-6.html
```

the htaccess file is in directory

this is my .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/(\S+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```